# SQL Pivot on undetermined columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have multiple tables I need to join and flatten. A table of users, a table of property types for the users, and a table containing the property values. Here's an example of the users table:

```
Id  User
1   Sam
2   Bill
```

And the property types:

```
Id  Order   Property
1   30      Weight
2   20      Hair Color
3   10      Eye Color
```

And the property values:

```
UserId  PropertyId  Value
1       3           Blue
1       2           Blond
1       1           170
2       3           Brown
2       2           Black
2       1           180
```

I'm looking to acheive a result like this:

```
User    Eye Color   Hair Color  Weight
Sam     Blue        Blond       170
Bill    Brown       Black       180
```

Notice the order of the property columns is driven by the Order column in the property type. And I'm not going to know in advance what the property names are or how many there might be.

Here is code to create the 3 tables.

```
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ProperyId int, DisplayOrder int, Property varchar(50))
DECLARE @TableB TABLE (UserId int, [User] varchar(50))
DECLARE @TableC TABLE (UserId int, PropertyId varchar(50), Value varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 1, 30, 'Weight'
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 2, 20, 'Hair Color'
INSERT INTO @TableA SELECT 3, 30, 'Eye Color'
INSERT INTO @TableB SELECT 1, 'Sam'
INSERT INTO @TableB SELECT 2, 'Bill'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 1, 3, 'Blue'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 1, 2, 'Blond'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 1, 1, '170'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 2, 3, 'Brown'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 2, 2, 'Black'
INSERT INTO @TableC SELECT 2, 1, '180'
select * from @TableA
select * from @TableB
select * from @TableC
```

Thanks in advance!
Steve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to get this to work while building the tables as temp tables was too much of a hassle, so I changed your schema code to make them actual tables (and corrected a typo in one of the column names).  The altered schema code and the result code can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0751a/3/0) on SQL Fiddle so you can test it, but I've also put the result code below. The key is that you have to use SQL to write the SQL you need (since you don't know what all the columns are going to be):

```
DECLARE
    @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @SQL_Statement NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @Columns = ISNULL( @Columns + ', ', '') + '[' + s.Property + ']' FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [Property] FROM TableA) AS s

SELECT @SQL_Statement = '
WITH cte_Flat AS
(
SELECT
    b.[User],
    a.[Property],
    C.[Value]
FROM
    TableC AS c
JOIN
    TableB AS b
ON
    c.[UserID] = b.[UserID]
JOIN
TableA AS a
ON
    c.[PropertyId] = a.[PropertyID]
)
SELECT
    [User],
    ' + @Columns + '
FROM
    cte_Flat
PIVOT
    (
      MAX([Value])
      for [Property] in (' + @Columns + ')
    ) AS u'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL  @SQL_Statement = @SQL_Statement
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks loads!!

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for you. You can code in your query the attributes, Property and Order, from the second table (TableA). So, you don't actually need it. You can achieve the same result with the first and the third table! This is because a user is not going to have two types of hair, eyes and weight, so the combination of userID and PropertyId  is going to be your key in the third table (TableC).

What I like to do in this cases is make a sub-query for each Property and then join them with the user table. I know this can be more code but is always easier for me when I'm dealing with more complicated data.

```
WITH EyeColor AS
(
SELECT
 UserId
 , Value
FROM
 TableC
WHERE
 PropertyId = 3
)
, HairColor AS
(
SELECT
 UserId
 , Value
FROM
 TableC
WHERE
 PropertyId = 2
)
, Weight AS
(
SELECT
 UserId
 , Value
FROM
 TableC
WHERE
 PropertyId = 2
)
------------------------------------
SELECT
 u.User AS NAME
 , e.Value AS EYECOLOR
 , h.Value AS HAIRCOLOR
 , w.Value AS WEIGHT
FROM
 TableB u
LEFT JOIN
 EyeColor e
ON u.Id = e.UserId
LEFT JOIN
 HairColor h
ON u.Id = h.UserId
LEFT JOIN
 Weight w
ON u.Id = w.UserId
```

Good Luck!

Comment: This works for the test data, but in the question they said that the don't know prior to runtime what all the Property names are - and this solution requires a separate CTE for every Property name.